# Import a csv file which was created at specific time instant in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have csv files in a specific directory with some random names created at some time instant. For example:

File.csv    created on  1st day at 11:00 hrs

Random.csv  created on  1st day at 11:15 hrs

Data.csv    created on  2nd day at 12:00 hrs

Log.csv     created on  3rd day at 13:10 hrs

I need to import a file which was created on 1st day in between 11:10-11:30 hrs (which correponds to "Random.csv")

Can somebody please let me know how do we go about this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os, time, datetime
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        d = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
        if d.day == 1 and d.hour == 11 and d.minute >= 10 and d.minute <= 30:
            print(file) #load your file here
```

Comment: simpler `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file))`

Comment: Thanks @Tanmay for your suggestons